# DataTables Editor - Adding Hyperlinks to URL's in DataTable

Tags: php, json, editor, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I'm looking to add hyperlinks to the table I have. I'm using DataTables Editor and at this point I'm just adding  tags in order to add the links to the url's. This requires me to parse through thousands of URL's and add the url tags. Any way for me to apply this to particular attributes in the table?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dataTables.tableTools.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dataTables.editor.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href-   "//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.1/css/dataTables.responsive.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/dataTables.editor.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/table.Brown_AP.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

    <!--FancyBox-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
 </script>

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".various").fancybox({
            maxWidth    : 1600,
            maxHeight   : 1200,
            fitToView   : true,
            width       : '100%',
            height      : '100%',
            autoSize    : true,
            closeClick  : false,
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none'
        });
});
</script>


<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('a.modalGeneric').fancybox({
            type: 'iframe',
            fitToView: true,
            autoSize: true,
            openEffect: 'fade',
            openSpeed: 'slow'
        });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>
        <center>
            AP
        </center>
        </h1>

        <table  cellspacing="0" class="display responsive nowrap" id="Brown_AP" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Building</th>
                    <th>Floor</th>
                    <th>Number of AP</th>
                    <th>Associated Floor Plans</th>
                    <th>AP</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>




        </table>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is the HTML the following is the PHP. How would I go about adding hyperlinks into the attributes pulled from the MYSQL.

```
<?php

/*
* Editor server script for DB table AP
* Automatically generated by http://editor.datatables.net/generator
*/

// DataTables PHP library
include( "lib/DataTables.php" );

// Alias Editor classes so they are easy to use
use
   DataTables\Editor,
   DataTables\Editor\Field,
   DataTables\Editor\Format,
   DataTables\Editor\Join,
   DataTables\Editor\Validate;


 // Build our Edit instance and process the data coming from _POST
   Editor::inst( $db, 'APS', 'Assoicated_Floor_Plans' )
     ->fields(
       Field::inst( 'Building' ),
       Field::inst( 'Floor' ),
       Field::inst( 'Number_Of_AP' ),
       Field::inst( 'Associated_Floor_Plans' ),
       Field::inst( 'AP' ),
       Field::inst( 'Status' )
      )
      ->process( $_POST )
      ->json();
```